# AWS CLI glacier command not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-glacier

I get an "Invalid choice" error.

```
ubuntu@server:/home/foo$ aws glacier
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [parameters]
aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

autoscaling                              | cloudformation
cloudfront                               | cloudsearch
cloudtrail                               | cloudwatch
datapipeline                             | directconnect
dynamodb                                 | ec2
elasticache                              | elasticbeanstalk
elastictranscoder                        | elb
emr                                      | iam
importexport                             | kinesis
opsworks                                 | rds
redshift                                 | route53
ses                                      | sns
sqs                                      | storagegateway
sts                                      | support
swf                                      | s3api
s3                                       | configure
help


ubuntu@server:/home/foo$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.2.9 Python/3.4.0 Linux/3.13.0-65-generic
```

Previously I installed it using: `ubuntu@server:/home/foo$ sudo apt-get install awscli`

What gives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a very old 1.2.9 version. According to the [changelog](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.rst) glacier support was added in 1.7.40, and current is 1.9.15.

Perhaps it is better to install it via pip, your ubuntu package repo seems outdated.

Comment: thank you! i was reading "1.2.9" as "1.9.2" and not thinking it was that old. i am using the standard ubuntu image offered by AWS, so i had no reason to suspect it could be so old! (upvoted/accepted)